# Recommended solutions to load a huge CSV file to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a large CSV file with size ranging from 500MB to 1GB on a weekly basis. The task is to load it to our SQL Server 2008 R2 database as a table.

The CSV file is "TAB" delimited and has 22 header columns. Some of the columns are optional which means they can be empty but some might contain commas.

What is your recommended approach to load it up in the database? It doesn't necessarily have to use scripting to achieve it; otherwise Python, .Net or Java is my preferred language.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers, Alex

Comment: Has to be a use case for [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). If fact, for the size of import files you're dealing with, this is probably the only sensible way. If you need to do some 'pre-processing' load the table with `BULK INSERT` and do the rest in SQL.

Comment: SSIS is another option.

Comment: I import them with HeidiSQL, works great for me.